# Not able to install unity-tweak-tool in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity-tweak-tool

Installation of Unity-tweak-tool is stuck at 0% and showing nothing. I've to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop.
I've checked internet connection and it is working fine.

[image]

Comment: you may try updating first `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool` or use a graphical manager instead, like synaptic.

Comment: @KevInski Didn't worked. Maybe there is some other problem. I got this at the end of update::: W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
1397BC53640DB551

Comment: Please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images (see [How do I save terminal output to a file?](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered the problem ever, the reason is that it use the `IPv6` address to access the software repository, but I found the `apt-get` may can't handle the `IPv6` address properly, so you should use the `IPv4` address instead.

You can try `sudo apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true install unity-tweak-tool`
Here are some materials about [Force Apt-Get to IPv4 or IPv6 on Ubuntu or Debian](https://www.vultr.com/docs/force-apt-get-to-ipv4-or-ipv6-on-ubuntu-or-debian)

Comment: Thanks! It's installed, but I still get that message in end that no public key available. Is it fine?

Comment: This `no public key` problem may be answered in the [How do I fix the GPG error "NO_PUBKEY"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey), I have no idea about this, sorry.